# SQL error text giving me a different value that the actual value

Tags: mysql

This is the line of code that is causing the error:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM 'accounts'.'users' WHERE email='$email' AND hash='$hash' AND active='0'") or die($mysqli->error);
```

and this is the error that shows:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''accounts'.'users' WHERE email='testemail@email.com' AND hash='76dc611d6eba' at line 1
```

However, if I print the value of hash I get this "76dc611d6ebaafc66cc0879c71b5db5c" the value that I want to search with and the value that is stored in the database. I am not sure if it is just being shortened for the error message of if something else is happening.

Comment: Also please see [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing from ' (apostrophe) to ` (backtick) or simply removed the single quotes from db/table name, so your query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `accounts`.`users` WHERE email='$email' AND hash='$hash' AND active='0'
```

Comment: Doing either of these (Removing and changing to backticks) gives me a "No database selected" error instead

Comment: @maxgoodman - you've not selected a DB when creating the mysqli object, reading [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) will help with this

Answer (score 0):

Try removing quotes around database and table name

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
 printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
 exit();
}

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM accounts.users WHERE email='$email' AND hash='$hash' AND active='0'") or die($mysqli->error);
```

Comment: find the updated solution. In your case database name will be accounts in place of world in first line